# Is it possible to exclude an app from "Complete action using"?

Tags: android, youtube, parental-control

I am creating a parental control app on non rooted device. What i did is that i managed to specify apps that i want the user to use but however i encounter a problem. Example, if i allow the user to use default browser, if he/she search for youtube in www.google.com and click on the link. It will prompt "Complete action using". This will allow the user to use YouTube app which i restrict him/her from using. I am wondering is there anyway that i can remove YouTube from "Complete action using" or can i kill the Youtube process once it is launch? [image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no way for your app to control the activity-chooser inside another app.

And in general, a "parental control" application that isn't integrated directly into the OS is a futile proposition. Your battle will be very much uphill.

For starters, even if you disable the Youtube app, the videos will still be playable directly in the browser.

Comment: Thank you @Dmitry Brant.